# How to prevent for loop from stopping when a 404 occurs?

Tags: c#, http, for-loop, try-catch, webclient

I have multiple links and I want to process all of them when the start button is pressed. If one of the links returns a 404, I want to skip it and move to the next one.

My current code is the following:

```
try
            {
                foreach (string s in txtInstagramUrls.Lines)
                {
                    if (s.Contains("something"))
                    {
                        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                        {
                            Match m = Regex.Match(wc.DownloadString(s), "(?<=og:image\" content=\")(.*)(?=\" />)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                            if (m.Success)
                            {
                                txtConvertedUrls.Text += m.Groups[1].Value + Environment.NewLine;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(WebException we)
            {
                if(we.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError && we.Response != null)
                {
                    var resp = (HttpWebResponse)we.Response;
                    if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                throw;
            }
```

The error shows on `continue;` saying `No enclosing loop out of which to break or continue`. I am not sure how to proceed from here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because when an exception is thrown, you have already left the `foreach` block and you are trying to `continue` but there is no loop to continue at that point. Here is your code simplified to show this:

```
try {
   foreach( string s in txtInstagramUrls.Lines ) {

   }
}
catch( WebException we ) {
   // There is no loop here to continue
}
```

You need to put the try inside the loop:

```
foreach( string s in txtInstagramUrls.Lines ) {
   try {
      // do something
   }
   catch( WebException we ) {
      continue;
      throw;
   }
}
```

So you need to change your code to following:

```
foreach( string s in txtInstagramUrls.Lines ) {
   try {
      if( s.Contains( "something" ) ) {
         using( WebClient wc = new WebClient() ) {
            Match m = Regex.Match( wc.DownloadString( s ), "(?<=og:image\" content=\")(.*)(?=\" />)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
            if( m.Success ) {
               txtConvertedUrls.Text += m.Groups[ 1 ].Value + Environment.NewLine;
            }
         }
      }
   }
   catch( WebException we ) {
      if( we.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError && we.Response != null ) {
         var resp = ( HttpWebResponse ) we.Response;
         if( resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound ) {
            continue;
         }
      }
      throw;
   }

}
```